# SQL Server index reorganization artefacts on SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, indexing

I have been reorganizing the indices of the tables used by an EAM software (Rimses). And it decreased the processtime/resource usage of our reports on our SSRS greatly. Which was my intention. But is it also possible I'm getting other 'results' from the reports?

Background information: the fragmentation of one of the main tables was 99% and I did a reorganize because I thought reorganizations/rebuild of indices were supposed to be done frequently. I'm a student!

Thank you for your time!
Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is it also possible I'm getting other 'results' from the reports

No.  Reorganizing/rebuilding indexes just checks the actual data in the table and makes sure the index matches, and fixes the index structure to be consistent.  Think of a deck of cards, and you get the cards in random order.  They keep getting inserted at the top of the stack whether that's where they belong or not.  You are just reshuffling the cards to be in the correct logical order.

The only possibility for changing the data here is if  your previous indexes were somehow wrong or corrupted.

When you remove records, it leaves holes in the deck as well which can cause fragmentation.

> I thought reorganizations/rebuild of indices were supposed to be done frequently

This is not necessarily the case.  If the table/index is write-heavy then it's a good idea to check for fragmentation regularly.

If the data doesn't change, or you have an auto-incrementing key, or you don't do many inserts, you're less likely to have fragmentation.  There's no hard and fast rule for this.  You'll find the answer to most SQL questions will be `It depends.`

Comment: The table is being used/updated daily and a lot, the fragmentation was 99%. So the right move was a reorganization/rebuild however messed up the table might have been?

Comment: @Jeff - I think so.  You should also bear in mind that small tables won't benefit much.  If the table is under a few hundred thousand rows I don't normally bother checking for fragmentation since the whole thing will be loaded into memory.  99% is pretty extreme, so you should probably put it in a maintenance schedule to be rebuilt weekly if possible.